# Not able to see modified pdf only on Adobe Acrobat reader on ios

Tags: ios, pdf, adobe, acrobat

I modified one file by adding one freetext and stickynotes is it, each and every viewer is able to show those annotations except the iOS version of acrobat reader, Any reason? you can check the last incremental update part.

here is the attached modified pdf http://www.filedropper.com/affectedjpn

Comment: Your incremental update is very suspicious, its cross reference table has the entries for objects 90, 91, and 92 pointing to the exact same offset 0000300371, where actually object 92 can be found while no objects 90 or 91 can be found at all. Any PDF viewer may consider this a broken table. Furthermore these three objects are referenced from the annotation array of page 1. Thus, any viewer may consider this list of annotations too suspicious to show.